# Insert node as first child always

Tags: java, xml

I have a basic XML document setup like this:

```
 <rss>
      <channel>
      </channel>
 </rss>
```

I would like to add new child nodes of the channel as the first node, so, say I'm looping through a collection of items, then the first item would be added like this:

```
 <rss>
      <channel>
           <item>Item 1</item>
      </channel>
 </rss>
```

Then the next item would added like this:

```
 <rss>
      <channel>
           <item>Item 2</item>
           <item>Item 1</item>
      </channel>
 </rss>
```

I've been trying to use:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(xmlFile));

 Element itemNode = doc.createElement("item");
 Node channelNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel").item(0);
 channelNode.appendChild(itemNode);
```

But it keeps adding new items to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
channelNode.appendChild(itemNode);
```

will always append the `itemNode` to the end of the list of children of `channelNode`. This is behavior is defined in the DOM Level 3 specification, and in [the JAXP documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29) as well:

> Node **appendChild**(Node newChild)
>                    throws DOMException
>
> ```
>     Adds the node newChild to the end of the list of children of this
> node (emphasis mine). If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed.
> ```

If you need to add at the beginning of the list of child nodes, you can use the [`insertBefore()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29) API method instead:

```
channelNode.insertBefore(itemNode, channelNode.getFirstChild());
```

Comment: Thanks.  Any reason why I get this error after I change to insertBefore?  channelNode and itemNode are not null. org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.insertBefore(InnerNodeImpl.java:86)  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: it should be channelNode.firstChild  instead of channelNode.getFirstChild().

Comment: @lorenzo, this is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @VineetReynolds this works flawlessly! saved the day!